# OR Operator for Java strings?

Tags: java

I'm coding a simple validation tool.

The "|" you see in the last bit isn't working, neither is "||". What should I be doing?

```
    if (flightClass.equals("1")) {
    System.out.println("Good input 1.");
}


if (flightClass.equals("2")) {
    System.out.println("Good input 2.");
    } 

if (!flightClass.equals("1" | "2")) {
    System.out.println("Bad input 2.");
```

Comment: Look into regular expressions. Or compare the String twice and OR the result.

Comment: If you have Java 7, you could use a switch statement. In this case, `default` would cover not `"1"` and not `"2"`.

Comment: Why don't you use if-else-if statements? 1st if can check for "1", second else-if for "2" and last else will by default work for your problem.  You can even go for ternary operator for a single line solution.

Answer (score 6):

Use this instead :

```
if (!flightClass.equals("1") && !flightClass.equals("2")) {
```

Although you could use `if ... else` instead :

```
if (flightClass.equals("1"))
{
    ...
}
else if (flightClass.equals("2"))
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Also using `switch` for Java 7+ would be another option.

Comment: @Christian Yes. I upvoted Obicere's comment to OP. But if they are having problems with `if`s and `else`s, I'm not sure talking about `switch ... case` will help.

Comment: @AntonH maybe your first if should be changed to `if(!flightClass.equals("1") && !flightClass.equals("2"))`? or `if(!(flightClass.equals("1") || flightClass.equals("2"))`?

Comment: @VasilLukach Yes, I changed to `&&`. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`String#matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method and regular expressions:

```
if (!flightClass.matches("1|2")) {
  // whatever
}
```

A side note: the answers that advice to use `!flightClass.equals("1") || !flightClass.equals("2")` are wrong. As one can easily see this boolean expression is always `true`. *Any* string is not equal to "1" or not equal to "2".

Here's the boolean table:

```
flightClass   !flightClass.equals("1")   !flightClass.equals("2")    OR result 
"0"           true                       true                        true 
"1"           false                      true                        true
"2"           true                       false                       true
```

The right way to go is `if (!(flightClass.equals("1") || flightClass.equals("2")))` or as Mr. De Morgan [advices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws): `if (!flightClass.equals("1") && !flightClass.equals("2"))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 if (!flightClass.equals("1") || !flightClass.equals("2")) {
        System.out.println("Bad input 2.");
    }
```